# How to run HelloJGraphT.java

Tags: java, classpath, libraries, jgrapht

I've added the JGraphtT to my classpath in netbeans IDE, I've done this by right clicking on Libraries and adding the Jar File/Folder.

But whenever I then access the file it shadows out the run button at the top of my screen.

Does anyone know how to compile and execute HelloJGraphT in Netbeans 7.3.1?

Comment: Care to explain what is the JGraphtT? Is [this](http://mste.illinois.edu/mmckelve/applets/graphtheory/org/_3pq/jgrapht/demo/HelloJGraphT.java) the source you're trying to run?

Comment: care to explain where we can download the JGraphtT?